# Find frequency of terms from Function

Tags: r, rstudio, frequency, tm

I need to find frequency of terms from the function that I have created that find terms with punctuation in them.

```
library("tm")
my.text.location <- "C:/Users/*/"
newpapers <- VCorpus(DirSource(my.text.location))
```

I read it then make the function:

```
library("stringr")
punctterms <- function(x){str_extract_all(x, "[[:alnum:]]{1,}[[:punct:]]{1,}?[[:alnum:]]{1,}")}
terms <- lapply(newpapers, punctterms)
```

Now I'm lost as to how will I find the frequency for each term in each file. Do I turn it into a DTM or is there a better way without it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This task is better suited for quanteda, not tm. Your function creates a list and removes everything out of the corpus. Using quanteda you can just use the quanteda commands to get everything you want.

Since you didn't provide any reproducible data, I will use a data set that comes with quanteda. Comments above the code explain what is going on. Most important function in this code is `dfm_select`. Here you can use a diverse set of selection patterns to find terms in the text.

```
library(quanteda)

# load corpus
my_corpus <- corpus(data_corpus_inaugural)
# create document features (like document term matrix)
my_dfm <- dfm(my_corpus)

# dfm_select can use regex selections to select terms
my_dfm_punct <- dfm_select(my_dfm, 
                     pattern = "[[:alnum:]]{1,}[[:punct:]]{1,}?[[:alnum:]]{1,}",
                     selection = "keep",
                     valuetype = "regex")

# show frequency of selected terms.
head(textstat_frequency(my_dfm_punct))

          feature frequency rank docfreq group
1 fellow-citizens        39    1      19   all
2       america's        35    2      11   all
3 self-government        30    3      16   all
4         world's        24    4      15   all
5        nation's        22    5      13   all
6           god's        15    6      14   all
```

Answer (score 0):

So I got it to work without using quanteda:

```
m <- as.data.frame(table(unlist(terms)))
names(m) <- c("Terms", "Frequency")
```